# Mixed order in DidSelectRowAt method

Tags: swift, api, uitableview, tableview

I dont understand why my debugger first goes do the bottom of the method, I mean, it ignores Api calls at first, goes to the bottom of the methos, and then goes back to the Api calls.

Like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondVC

//Method for AlamoFire API call 1 here
APIManager.shared.getDetailsCity(city: indexPath.row){ (details) in
//code for the method
}

//Method2 for AlamoFire API call 2 here
APIManager.shared.getDetailsCountry(country: indexPath.row){ (details) in
//code for the method2
}
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC!, animated: true)
}
```

`code for the method` and `code for the method2` is produced after all other things.

Also, sometimes `code for the method2` is read before `code for the method`

Comment: API call is asynchron. completion closure ( { (details) in // code for the method } ) will be executed if api call is finished.

Comment: Ah ok @StefanWieland . Do you have any suggestions? It mostly updates my secondVC's data in `code for method`s properly, but sometimes looks like one of the `code for method`s is late o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stefan pointed out, the APIManager calls seem to execute the closure asynchronously.

You could do the following:

- Create an integer property `index` in the second view controller
- when the user taps on a cell, instantiate that view controller and set `vc.index = indexPath.row` before pushing it

In the second view controller, in `viewDidLoad`:

- start a progress indicator
- give the user some info, like "loading data - please wait"
- call the API manager with the `index` value

In the closures, update the UI (make sure this code runs in the main thread)

After all closures have returned (maybe use a dispatch group), hide the progress indicator

Comment: Thanks. Do you think delegates&protocols are good idea for this?